# aws machine learning endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning

I have generated endpoint after evaluation of machine learning model.

Created and endpoint

Which is the best way to request and use the endpoint to make a prediction in our web application.? 
We are looking to use the php sdk

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This documentation should help you with everything you need: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/machinelearning.html

You just need to use the predict method.